# liferay site owner view only his site membership

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In liferay I need to restrict site owner should view only his members and Site owner don't see the other site members. How can I restrict?

liferay version:liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way, **if you haven't specific requirements that need for using sites**, is to use different Liferay Portal Instances.

In this way any portal will have its own users, configurations, groups, etc.

Take a look [here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-portal-instances-0).